# View RAID configuration without restarting

Tags: raid, configuration

I would like to know if it is to view the RAID configuration of a server without restarting.

Is there any such utility for Windows?

Samuel.A

Answer (score 5):

Usually RAID controllers are shipped with a piece of software for exactly that purpose (and more - think of alerts via mail and SNMP).

If the controller came with the server, it's likely that you find the software in the support/download area of your server vendor.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the RAID hardware being used. You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: I like "it depends" even though PEras answer was more informative ^^